# A string encoding issuse on IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstringencoding

I came across a problem with string encoding in ios development. The story is as below:

I create some values in Chinese and then create a NSDictionary for those values, the dictionary is used as parameter for network request:

[image]

```
- (void)createActivity
{
    NSString *actionTheme = titleF.text;
    NSString *actionTitle = biaotiF.text;
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:actionTheme, @"actionTheme", actionTitle, @"actionTitle",nil];
    [self networkrequest:];
}
```

Then some work has been done for the dictionary:

Transform the dictionary to the form of JSON as the type of NSString.

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:param options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Encoding the string , because of Chinese word in the string.

```
NSString *urlEncodedString = [jsonString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

At last a full url was create with the string above:

```
http://app.ic100.com/action/add?paramJson=%7B%22actionTheme%22%3A%22%E6%88%96%E8%80%85%E5%92%8C%E7%94%9F%E6%B4%BB%22%2C%22actionSite%22%3A%22%E5%8E%A (something like this)
```

I use the third party "ASIFormDataRequest" for network request, and I also set the StringEncoding:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *requstHttp  = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] init];
[requstHttp setStringEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
....
```

All the datas has been sent to the server successfully, but when I request these data from the server and show then on the iphone. It turn to be unreadable text:

[image]

I have carefully checked all the place that I should encode or decode the string, and only utf8 is used. What`s more , for the server side , no other encoding used either. And my colleague has tested sent data from Android platform, no problem. So I think maybe I have missed some points.

Any advise?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are url-encoding the JSON string.  Also if you have issues with reading data from the server, show *that* code, not the code that sends data.

Answer (score 0):

By using the class **Base64** you can encode or decode the string.

Add Base64 class in your project from [HERE](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64)

see the mehode in class to encode.

Encode:

```
+ (NSString *)stringWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string;

- (NSString *)base64EncodedString;
```

Decode:

```
- (NSString *)base64DecodedString;
```

Comment: Why do you need a category at all, when all the real implementation is already in `NSData`?  It might be more convenient, but it's certainly not necessary.

Comment: So what value does your answer add?  What has base-64 got to do with the issue in the first place?